# Sneak around with someone (meaning)

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

I came across this expression "*sneak around with someone*". What does it mean? Does it have to do with "*date someone*"?

Here is an example:

> - We all know that John has been **sneaking around with** Jenny for five years now.

Comment: yes, they have been secretely dating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To sneak around with someone" means to be dating with some amount of (and motivation for) secrecy. It might be an extramarital affair, or a relationship of which some others might disapprove.